# How do I make it so the user has continuous input but can stop this with the use of a symbol?

Tags: java, if-statement, for-loop, reverse

I currently have the following code:

```
    import java.io.*;
    import java.util.*;


    public class Reverser
{   

public void run() throws IOException
{
  String text;
  String reverseText = "";

  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

  System.out.println("Please enter text");
  text = input.nextLine();

  int length = text.length();

  for (int i=length-1; i >= 0; i--)


  reverseText = reverseText + text.charAt(i);



  System.out.println("Your characters in reverse are: "+reverseText);

   }

   }
```

I now want to make it so that once the user types in something, they can then type in something else after without having to re-run the program. I then want to make it so that if the character '*' is entered, it ends and you can no longer enter anything. Is an if statement required after the for loop?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a loop of some sort, e.g. a `while` loop and test the input each time.

For example:

```
while (true) {
    System.out.println("Please enter text");
    text = input.nextLine();
    if ("*".equals(text)) {
        break;
    }

    // ...code to use 'text'...
}
```

The `while (true)` loop will run forever, but the test `if ("*".equals(text))` will break the loop (using the `break` keyword) if an asterix is entered.

Answer (score 0):

> Is an if statement required after the for loop?

No, I don't think so.

Here is one of the methods to do this

```
String text = "";
String reverseText = "";

Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

while (true) {
    System.out.println("Please enter text");
    text = input.nextLine();

    if (text.equals("*")) {
        break;
    }

    int length = text.length();

    for (int i=length-1; i >= 0; i--)
        reverseText = reverseText + text.charAt(i);
    System.out.println("Your characters in reverse are: "+reverseText);
    reverseText = "";
}
```

Explanation: The code inside the `while (true)` block basically keeps looping and looping until `input.nextLine()` returns `"*"`. That is what `break` does.

You can also call `trim()` on `text` so that the loop will also stop if the user enters the asterisk with some whitespace characters.

```
if (text.trim().equals("*"))
```

Alternatively, you can place the above condition in the parentheses of the while loop.

```
String text = "";
String reverseText = "";

Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

while (!text.trim().equals("*")) {
    System.out.println("Please enter text");
    text = input.nextLine();

    int length = text.length();

    for (int i=length-1; i >= 0; i--)
        reverseText = reverseText + text.charAt(i);
    System.out.println("Your characters in reverse are: "+reverseText);
    reverseText = "";
}
```

But this will behave a little bit differently than the first one. The first method will not print the reverse of * if you ever entered one because the if is placed before the for loop. On the other hand, the second method *will* print the reverse of * because the check is done after each iteration of the while loop, as if an if statement is placed at the end of the loop.

Comment: That's great but when I enter another input, the reserve output adds it on. E.g. if i put 'hi there' in it would say 'ereht ih' and then if i enter something else e.g. 'hello' it would say: 'ollehereht ih'. Is there a way to clear what was previously entered?

Comment: @J.Extra2 It's simple. Just set `reverseText` back to `""` after printing the reverse (inside the loop!)

Comment: @J.Extra2 Maybe I didn't say it clearly enough. Anyway, see my edited answer.